# I can load xml file at localhost but not in production server

Tags: php, xml, external

Until today, I was able to read daily exchange rates form Turkish Central Bank xml url. However, today, customers informed us that they cannot make online transaction on our website.Then I checked and realized that I can not read the contents of xml file. I am using php for that. Here is the code:

```
 $tcmb = ("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml"); 
 if (false === $tcmb) {
     echo "Failed loading XML\n";
     foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
         echo "\t", $error->message;
     }
 } 
 else { 
 $euro_satis = $tcmb->Currency[3]->BanknoteSelling;
 }
```

This returned with a "failed to load external entity" error.

Then I tried curl in order to make sure if file is closed to external reach.

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml"); 
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
 $output = curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);
 $tcmb = simplexml_load_string($output);
 $euro_satis = $tcmb->Currency[3]->BanknoteSelling;
```

This returned null.

Then i tried both of the codes on local with Xampp (Apache Server) and both worked fine.

I tried to download the xml file from url. Again, it worked on local but not on production server. They all were working fine till today.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could their server be blocking your server's IP? Do they have some sort of rate limiting set up? If the file wasn't meant for external scraping, maybe they identified your server as a scraper and blocked the IP? I'm not sure how I'd test for this... Maybe if you had access to another webserver where you could try it? Also, in your CURL attempt, try getting the headers as well, maybe those will give more details.

Comment: Maybe just download the file on a another server, then send to the main server. Or store it in a database. What happens if you open that file in a browser on the Server?

Comment: Agreed, get the cURL response headers and check the response from the server including status code.

Comment: Just tried on another server, and it is not working there as well. All of a sudden, virtual POS stopped working too. It may be related to exchange rate surges after Ukranian crisis.

Comment: Tried to download on another server too. File comes empty.

Comment: Again, is there a specific HTTP status code associated with the response, when it's blank?And does it work from your browser?

Comment: $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

$header = substr($output, 0, $header_size);

$body = substr($output, $header_size);

added those line and all returned empty...

Comment: got something from logs:

"PHP Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."

Comment: After seeing logs, I have realized that it is a server error, vmware update solved the issue.